# Facebook iOS SDK - Upload Photo Failing with strange error

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

```
2013-04-05 21:09:24.502 Pazam[72689:c07] FBSDKLog: Request <#1111>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?format=json&sdk=ios
  Method:   POST
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.0.8
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
  Body Size:    0 kB
  Attachments:  
    format: json
    sdk:    ios
    picture:    <Image - 984 kB>

2013-04-05 21:09:24.503 Pazam[72689:c07] FBSDKLog: FBURLConnection <#1114>:
  URL: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?format=json&sdk=ios'

2013-04-05 21:09:29.627 Pazam[72689:c07] FBSDKLog: FBURLConnection <#1114>:
  Duration: 5123 msec
Response Size: 0 kB
  MIME type: text/plain
2013-04-05 21:09:29.627 Pazam[72689:c07] FBSDKLog: Response <#1111>
Duration: 5124 msec
Size: 0 kB
Response Body:
(
        {
        body =         {
            "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = "";
        };
        code = 200;
    }
)
```

Check it out, im unable to figure out the problem, the only thing thats looks odd is the body size (0kb) , yet the picture size is ok.

Any ideas ?

UPDATE

Changed the sdk to the latest one and still nothing :(